# Installation script issue for shifting folder structure

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp, installation

When we moved Documents and Settings folder completely from C to D drive , the product addon installation is not working , this ends up with popup windowsFolderSplit(0):C  and error Folder doesn't exisit? For a systems having single partition this is working fine but only for multiple partitions this is not working

Here is the bit of vbscript code used in the installation script, Do i need to do any modification here ??

```
Dim windowsFolder      ' For finding shortcut location
Dim windowsFolderSplit ' For isolating the WINDOWS drive

windowsFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(WindowsFolder)
If DEBUG = "D1" Then        
   MsgBox "windowsFolder:" & windowsFolder
End If

windowsFolderSplit = Split(windowsFolder, "\", -1, 1)

If DEBUG = "D1" Then        
   MsgBox "windowsFolderSplit(0):" & windowsFolderSplit(0)
   MsgBox "windowsFolderSplit(1):" & windowsFolderSplit(1)
End If

Set docAndSetFolder = fso.GetFolder(windowsFolderSplit(0) & "\Documents and Settings")
```

Does it hardcoding values in to 'C' drive?

Comment: What do you mean with "product addon" exactly?

Comment: @reporter that is product patch i meant. Product works fine but when i started patch installation it throwing this one. That vbscript is part of patch installation  ,,Does it hardcoding values in to 'C' drive?

Comment: Yes, the "spacial windows folders" are often links they point to a particular path on your hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

SpecialFolders ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)):

```
Dim objShell As Object
Dim strPath As String

Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
wscript.echo strPath
```

or optionally:

```
Set S = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set E = S.Environment
WScript.Echo E("USERPROFILE")
```

Comment: Will this code fetch Documents and Settings folder if that is only existing in D folder not in C??

Comment: the first code will get the special folders listed in the MSDN article, regardless of where they are. The second code gets environment variables - type `SET` at a command line to see what variables are open to be returned